# How can I get getmac output into a variable in a batch file and keep the format

Tags: batch-file

From other questions I've found here, I thought this would work

```
SET LF=^


SET output=
SET getmac_cmd=getmac /v /fo list
FOR /F "USEBACKQ tokens=*" %%F in (`!getmac_cmd!`) DO (
    set output=!output!!LF!%%F
)
ECHO !output!
```

The output of that command directly looks like

```
Connection Name:  Local Area Connection
Network Adapter:  Intel Something
Physical Address: 00-00-00-00-00-00
Transport Name:   Media disconnected

Connection Name:  Bluetooth Network Connection
Network Adapter:  Bluetooth Something
Physical Address: 00-00-00-00-00-00
Transport Name:   Media disconnected
```

But when run through the batch script, I get

```
Connection Name:  Local Area Connection
Network Adapter:  Intel Something
Physical Address: 00-00-00-00-00-00
Transport Name:   Media disconnected
Connection Name:  Bluetooth Network Connection
Network Adapter:  Bluetooth Something
Physical Address: 00-00-00-00-00-00
Transport Name:   Media disconnected
```

Any clue what I can change to get it to preserve the actual blank line between sections?

Comment: Why do you need the entire text in a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty line is missing in the output, because [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) ignores empty lines. User [Mofi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3074564) already demonstrates in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45333787) how to overcome this by using `findstr /N`:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(set LF=^
%= empty line =%
)
set "output="
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%E in ('getmac /V /FO LIST ^| findstr /N /R "^"') do (
    set "output=!output!!LF!%%F"
)
echo/!output!
endlocal
```

However, this fails if exclamation marks occur, because `%%F` becomes expanded while [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, which consumes `!`. Furthermore, leading colons (although very unlikely in the output of `getmac`) become removed, because `for /F` treates subsequent delimiters as one.

To solve these issues, the following code could be used (see the explanatory remarks):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

(set LF=^
%= empty line =%
)

set "output="
for /F "delims=" %%E in ('getmac /V /FO LIST ^| findstr /N /R "^"') do (
    rem // Expand `for` variable `%%F` while delayed expansion is disabled:
    set "line=%%F"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem /* Remove the leading line number and the first colon by sub-string replacement
    rem    (like `!line:*:=!`, see below) so every other leading colons are maintained;
    rem    since delayed expansion is toggled within the `for /F` loop, variable `output`
    rem    would not survive the `endlocal` barrier, so let another `for /F` loop carry
    rem    the whole assignment string, including the variable name, beyond `endlocal`;
    rem    that way, we do not have to care about empty strings or the default `eol`: */
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ("output=!output!!LF!!line:*:=!") do (
        endlocal
        rem // Again the `for` variable is expanded while delayed expansion is disabled:
        set "%%A"
    )
)

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo/!output!
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

Answer (score 1):

The help output on several pages on running in a command prompt window `for /?` explains that command **FOR** ignores blank lines.

A solution is using command **FINDSTR** with option `/N` to output the line number before each found line which simply finds all lines including blank lines and remove from this output the line numbers.

The output of `getmac /v /fo list | findstr /R /N "^"` is:

```
1:Connection Name:  Local Area Connection
2:Network Adapter:  Intel Something
3:Physical Address: 00-00-00-00-00-00
4:Transport Name:   Media disconnected
5:
6:Connection Name:  Bluetooth Network Connection
7:Network Adapter:  Bluetooth Something
8:Physical Address: 00-00-00-00-00-00
9:Transport Name:   Media disconnected
```

The batch file to process this output and assign it to environment variable `output` without the line numbers is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


set output=
for /F "tokens=1* delims=:" %%A in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\getmac.exe /v /fo list 2^>^&1 ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^"') DO set "output=!output!!LF!%%B"
echo !output!
endlocal
```

The code captures also the error output of **GETMAC** written to **STDERR** by duplicating the handle with **STDOUT** which is piped to **STDIN** of **FINDSTR**.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `getmac /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Read also the Microsoft article about [Using Command Redirection Operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for an explanation of `2>&1` and `|`.

The operators `>`, `&` and `|` must be escaped here with caret character `^` to be interpreted first as literal characters on parsing **FOR** command line by Windows command interpreter.

Later is executed by **FOR** in a separate command process in the background the command line:

```
C:\Windows\System32\getmac.exe /v /fo list 2>&1 | C:\Windows\System32\findstr.exe /N /R "^"
```