# CMD substitute phrase containing special characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, windows-7

I need to do a very simple thing: substitute one frase with another. This must be done by CMD batch file (for Windows 7). The frase to be subsitituted can be in any position in txt file line (and in many lines).

The problem is the frase to be substituted contains ":" and "!" characters. I am not very skilled in batch files (to put it mildly), though I spend some hours especially to learn about this specific problem. It looks very complicated for me. At last, by chance, I overided the issue, but... I feel it is a barbarity how I did it.

The real line with the frase which should be substituted is e.g.:

```
"21:12:45 WARNING: No video signal present!"
```

The frase which should be substituted is:

```
"WARNING: No video signal present!"
```

The frase, which it should be substituted with is:

```
"Recognition suspended"
```

I have found this code: https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=41188.0

It works fine, except cannot work with "!" as I see, and escape char "^" never works. But I noticed that although it doesn't work properly - it trims the exclamation mark. Here are real strings before (b) and after (a):

```
(b)20:42:18 WARNING: No video signal present!
(a)20:42:18 WARNING: No video signal present
```

So I add 2 other lines to the code and this does the thing. The whole code is now:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set txtfile=D:\wfc\testlib\test.txt
set newfile=D:\wfc\testlib\new_test.txt
if exist "%newfile%" del /f /q "%newfile%"
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%txtfile%) do (
   set newline=%%a
   set newline=!newline:No video signal present!=!
   set newline=!newline:No video signal present=!
   set newline=!newline:WARNING:=Suspend recognition!
   echo !newline! >> %newfile%
)
```

First crucial line cuts "!", 
second line substitutes "No video signal present" with nothing (trims it), 
third line substitutes the rest "Warning:" with desirable "Suspend recognition".

And at the end I have:

```
(b)20:42:18 WARNING: No video signal present!
(a)20:42:18 Suspend recognition
```

I feel this could be done elegantly. Besides I am not sure, if my way is not dangerous for some reason (data damage etc.). Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done easier.

First of all, it is not the line `set newline=!newline:No video signal present!=!` that removes the `!` character, but it is the line `set newline=%%a`, because there is [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) enabled when the [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variable reference `%%a` is expanded, which happens before delayed expansion, hence an orphaned exclamation mark appears that is simply removed.

The key to success is to disable delayed expansion during expansion of `%%a` and to enable it afterwards. In the [sub-string replacement syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html) the `:` does not cause any problems; neither does the `!` in the search string, given it is not the first character. So the following code should work:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "txtfile=D:\wfc\testlib\test.txt"
set "newfile=D:\wfc\testlib\new_test.txt"

> "%newfile%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%a in ("%txtfile%") do (
        set "newline=%%a"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!newline:WARNING: No video signal present!=Recognition suspended!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

I also changed the following items:

- improved the syntax of [`set`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) by using quotes to avoid trouble with some special characters;
- avoided interim variable `newline`, so did the string manipulation directly in the `echo` line;
- quoted file path/name to avoid problems with white-spaces, hence using [`usebackq`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) option;
- replaced the `tokens=*` by the [`delims=`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) option in order to keep leading white-spaces; to avoid loss of lines that begin with `;` due to the default [`eol`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) option, I used the odd-looking unquoted option string syntax as this is the only way (!) to have no `delims` and `eol` defined at the same time (you cannot write `"delims= eol="` as this would define `"` as the `eol` character; `"eol=  delims="` would define the <kbd>SPACE</kbd>, and `"eol=delims="` the `d`);
- [redirected](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) whole `for` loop, so no initial file deletion necessary, and the performance is a lot better, because the output file has to be opened and closed once only, not in every iteration;
- `echo Text > "file.ext"` returns a trailing <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (actually the one in front of `>`); this is avoided by the above item; in general, this can be avoided when using the reversed redirection syntax `> "file.ext" echo Text`;
- `echo !VAR!` returns `ECHO is on|off.` in case variable `VAR` is empty; to avoid this or other unexpected output, the odd-looking but safe syntax `echo(!VAR!` is used;
- avoided immediate (`%`) expansion when delayed expansion is enabled to avoid loss of `!`;

---

To keep empty lines that appear in the original file, change the code to this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

set "txtfile=D:\wfc\testlib\test.txt"
set "newfile=D:\wfc\testlib\new_test.txt"

> "%newfile%" (
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%txtfile%"') do (
        set "newline=%%a"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "newline=!newline:WARNING: No video signal present!=Recognition suspended!"
        echo(!newline:*:=!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The [`findstr` command](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) is used to prefix every line of the input file by a line number plus a colon (`/N` option). Then the sub-string replacement is done. Finally, everything up to and including the first `:`, hence the line number prefix becomes removed.

Comment: `"usebackq tokens=*` is a poor choice as it will strip leading space and tab characters. Better to use `"usebackq delims="`. But that still has problems with `:` in first position due to default EOL. The best option is the awful looking `usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^=`, without any quotes, as it disables both DELIMS and EOL.

Comment: Thanks aschipfl a lot. This works. Although I came yeasterday another problem - there are some empty lines in the real files

Comment: Sorry I pressed Enter incidentally - the full comment is: thanks aschipfl a lot. This works. Although I came yeasterday another problem - there are some empty lines in the real files. As it looks these empty lines must be preserved or the file is useless... Thanks dbenham also - it works as well, even if with my worm's-eye view I cannot understand the twists and turns up there. Best, mac.

Comment: To maintain empty lines, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45336846)...

Comment: Thanks a lot. But there is a problem - empty lines are filled with     
    `ECHO jest wyĄczone` what means `"ECHO is off"` in Polish.

Comment: Sorry, my fault, the `echo` syntax needs to be slightly modified -- see my updated answer...

Comment: That's great work really :) . Thank you a lot. I can't imagine how it is possible to figure out meaning and order of all these crazy little chars `( ^ ! * `. Chapeau bas!

Answer (score 0):

Substituting a phrase is pretty easy to do in a .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-Content -Path '.\subfrase-in.txt' |" ^
        "ForEach-Object { $_ -replace 'WARNING: No video signal present!', 'Recognition suspended' }"
```

Comment: Doubt the OP downvoted. Maybe the fact that you say batch file but then use poweshell? Yes you can wrap powershell in batch but then why not just use powershell on its own?

Comment: I agree about just using PowerShell on its own, but the OP specified that it had to be done "by CMD batch." Some do not mind using `find.exe`, `taskkill.exe`, or `net.exe`, but balk at using `powershell.exe`. It is just another command on the machine. Why should it not be used?

Comment: I was just thinking of reasons for the downvote. Perhaps just specify wrapping powershell commands in batch.